# Message appears when I disconnect the network(SamsungSmart tv app)

Tags: javascript, html5-video, samsung-smart-tv

I am developing samsung smart tv app to play live streaming video,
for this  **I want to show error message when network is disconnected**

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has a special API for that, check e.g. here (http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00128/index.html).

Note that during QA they are in Samsung testing heavily this feature.